# Choosing a distance metric and a clustering algorithm for time series

Tags: time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning

For every entity I have a corresponding time series which is built by a sliding window (win_size=7d, win_shift=3d, so we have overlapped windows)

With every win-shift, we count how many users are currently using the entity.

So we might see a time series that looks like this:
$$[128, 105, 87, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 19, ...]$$

Or a time series that looks like this:
$$[5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, ...]$$

Or
$$[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...]$$

(By the way, I padded with $(-1)$ to indicate that no information is available from that point and on)

I've encountered with some [clustering algorithm](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/tslearn.clustering.html#module-tslearn.clustering) that are dedicated for time series, and some time series similarity metrics like DTW.

I tried to use [TimeSeriesKMeans](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans.html#tslearn.clustering.TimeSeriesKMeans) with `metric='dtw'` but for some reason very "far" time series clustered together. I believe it has something to do with `dtw` which might be indifferent for the "intensity" of time the series? For the same reason, Pearson correlation might not be a good choice, right?

Also, should I normalize the time series? I thought about min-max normalization where max is global. What do you think?

**EDIT:**
Interestingly, increasing the number of clusters helped, but I still see weird stuff like $$[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 477, 477, 477, 477, 450]$$ is clustered with time series like $$[98, 96, 96, 95, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 94, 93, 93, 92, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 88, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 84, 84, 84, 84, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 81, 81, 78, 77, 75, 73, 72]$$